# Excel Nested If Argument error

Tags: excel

I was trying to write an IF statement for Positive Correlation values. The function is given below. I am getting an error and it says too many arguments.

`=IF(B16 = 1, "Perfect Positive Correlation" ,IF(AND(B16>= 0.9, B16< 1),"Very Strong Correlation" ,IF(AND(B16>=0.7, B16<0.9),"Strong Correlation" ,IF(B16>=0.4,B16<0.7),"Moderate Correlation" ,IF(AND(B16>=0.2, B16 <0.4),"Low Correlation" ,IF(AND(B16>0, B16 <0.2),"Very low Correlation" ,IF(B16 = 0, "No Correlation", "NA")))))))`

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: Why not use a lookup table and VLOOKUP function? It would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lookup table with index/match functions.

[image: Lookup table with Index/Match functions]

Comment: This too helped a lot David. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Missing AND  `AND(B16>=0.4,B16<0.7)`

```
=IF(B16 = 1, "Perfect Positive Correlation",IF(AND(B16>= 0.9, B16< 1),"Very Strong Correlation",IF(AND(B16>=0.7, B16<0.9),"Strong Correlation",IF(AND(B16>=0.4,B16<0.7),"Moderate Correlation",IF(AND(B16>=0.2, B16 <0.4),"Low Correlation",IF(AND(B16>0, B16 <0.2),"Very low Correlation",IF(B16 = 0, "No Correlation", "NA")))))))
```

Comment: I was literally about to click post for the same answer... +1

Comment: @pnuts Sometimes there are multiple solution for an answer but it always a good idea to suggest something which OP understands or what OP is trying to achieve. If you have a great answer you can rather post it as separate answer so that it can be useful for later readers. I am not happy this a a reason to downvote.