# Excel nested if too many arguments fix without lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I know this question have been asked before. I want to know if it's possible to fix it without using a lookup with index function. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599013/excel-nested-if-argument-error) question and I tried adding AND with no success.

This is my formula:

> =IF(C49="", "", IF(R49="2 months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+2,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="3
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+3,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="4
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+4,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="5
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+5,DAY(C49)),IF(R49="6
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+6,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="7
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+7,DAY(C49)),  IF(R49="8
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+8,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="9
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+9,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="10
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+10,DAY(C49)), IF(R49="11
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+11,DAY(C49)),IF(R49="12
> months/mois",DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+12,DAY(C49)), "0"))))))))))))

How can I modify this formula to not get a too many arguments error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid multiple IF statements by using:

```
=DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+LEFT(R49,2),DAY(C49))
```

This will automatically add months from two first characters of `R49` cell.
You only need to add the condition to check if C49 is empty.

EDIT:

If you want to check if C49 and R49 are empty you can use:

```
=IF(C49="","",IFERROR(DATE(YEAR(C49),MONTH(C49)+LEFT(R49,2),DAY(C49)),"0"))
```

> if C49 is 31st Dec and you add 2 months what result do you expect?

If you want it to be Feb 28th, then you should use @barry houdini 's approach. My formula (based on your nested IF) will return Mar 3rd.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you. This will also make my other formulas way simpler. Enjoy the 1000 rep :)

Comment: You could make that even simpler with EDATE function - =EDATE(C49,LEFT(R49,2)+0), although sometimes the result might be different - if C49 is 31st Dec and you add 2 months what result do you expect?

Comment: Only one thing about your answer: In my original formula I was checking if the value was Null. How can I add it to this formula

Comment: @barryhoudini I'm not sure.. Feb 28th I guess.

Comment: EDATE would give you 28th Feb - Try this version with the null check - `=IF(C49="","",EDATE(C49,LEFT(R49,2))`